# How to read a string with cJSON

Tags: c, json, cjson

I am using [cJSON](https://github.com/kbranigan/cJSON) but somehow I can't get the strings to work:

```
void myfile()
{
  cJSON* type = NULL;
  char text1[]="{\n\"name\": \"Jack (\\\"Bee\\\") Nimble\", \n\"format\": {\"type\":       \"rect\", \n\"width\":      1920, \n\"height\":     1080, \n\"interlace\":  false,\"frame rate\": 24\n}\n}";
  cJSON * root = cJSON_Parse(text);
  cJSON * format = cJSON_GetObjectItem(root,"format"); 
  int framerate = cJSON_GetObjectItem(format,"frame rate")->valueint;
  type = cJSON_GetObjectItem(format,"type")->valuestring;
  char * rendered = cJSON_Print(root);
  cJSON_Delete(root);
  printf("rate = %d, type = %s \n", framerate, type) ;
}
```

I only get garbage. I also tried this but it didn't even compile:

`char *type[] = cJSON_GetObjectItem(format,"type")->valuestring;`

Comment: `cJSON* type = NULL;`, `type = %s` - are you sure you should be printing it this way? If `cJSON` isn't typedefed to a `char` you get UB.

Comment: I want a char at the end so i can print it with `%s` what do I have to do for that ?

Comment: try `char *type = cJSON_GetObjectItem(format,"type")->valuestring;` and `printf("rate = %d, type = %s \n", framerate, type) ;` move to before `cJSON_Delete(root);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char text[]="{\n\"name\": \"Jack (\\\"Bee\\\") Nimble\", \n\"format\": {\"type\":       \"rect\", \n\"width\":      1920, \n\"height\":     1080, \n\"interlace\":  false,\"frame rate\": 24\n}\n}";
cJSON * root   = cJSON_Parse(text);
cJSON * format = cJSON_GetObjectItem(root,"format"); 
cJSON * type   = cJSON_GetObjectItem(format,"type");
int framerate = cJSON_GetObjectItem(format,"frame rate")->valueint;
char * rendered = cJSON_Print(root);
printf("%s\n", rendered);
printf("rate = %d, type = %s \n", framerate, type->valuestring);
free(rendered);
cJSON_Delete(root);
```